# Production Kafka configuration in Lagom Framework with Kubernetes?

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes, lagom

How to configure kafka cluster in lagom framework in kubernetes in production mode.

Its expecting `kafka_native` service while starting service container.

Cassandra `cas_native` successfully configured but kafka not working

Comment: Have you read [the blog post](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/lagom-kubernetes-k8s-deploy-microservices/) about it?

Comment: @erip yes we read that blog and we deployed kubernetes without kafka

that blog only mentioned cassandra not kafka

Comment: we even contracted lightbend about this but they are asking to take enterprice subscription for conductr, but not supporting on kubernetes

Comment: [This](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/KafkaClient.html#Lagom-Kafka-Client1) could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Kubernetes you can use [service locator DNS](https://github.com/lightbend/service-locator-dns) and take advantage of Kube DNS Service... You have to have a headless service in front of  Kafka...